# How do I switch the default accounts in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

How do I take the default off of my secondary Google Drive account, so my primary account shows up first in Google Drive?

Answer (score 5):

You can do the following.

1. Log out from all Google accounts.
2. Log in Google with the account that you want to use as primary first.
3. Login with your secondary Google account (add account).
4. Go to drive.google.com (It will be by default open with primary account). You can also switch account from there.

If you want to switch primary account of Drive, log out from all Google accounts and follow the above steps.

Comment: I have done this but it does not work. The account I log in with first is shown as "Default" in the list of accounts, and is first in the list, but if I open a link to a drive document, it always opens with the second account in the list.

Comment: @polm23 If your link has `/drive/u/1/` that could be the reason. Change it to just `/drive/`. Links can be altered to suggest the account to open it with. `/drive/u/0/` or `/drive/` is primary account, `/drive/u/1/` is the next account, and so on. (I wish `/drive/` would be the last chosen account instead, like what YouTube does... oh well.)